# Vnstat showing large amount of traffic

Tags: networking, lubuntu, traffic, vnstat

I am using lubuntu 16.04, and have `vnstat` to monitor my traffic, since in our students home we have a limit of 30Gb per month.

Everything was fine with the program till yesterday when I tried upgrading the data base several time, and it did not work. It was always showing something in order of kbytes. After PC restart, I have updated the `vnstat` data base again with `vnstat -u`  and it showed 4GB received and 4GB transmitted.

Well the problem is that I was working around 40 minutes on the PC, and from these 40 minutes, I had been on the internet for 15-20 minutes max, the rest of the time i have been disconected, and while i was connected i downloaded only 2-3 eclipse themes,.

And last but not least, my connection is not capable of generating 4GB of traffic for such a short amount of time.

I would be very grateful if some will tell me what is going on here, because I cannot explain it myself.

Comment: Could you check your `/var/log/syslog` for any vnstat/vnstatd errors? Like: `vnstatd[6771]: Error: Unable to create database backup "/var/lib/vnstat/.eth0"`
I had similar problem, when vnstatd didn't update database because incorrect ownership. This answer help me solve this: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/500663/vnstat-not-updating/502667#502667](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500663/vnstat-not-updating/502667#502667)

Comment: i have the same problem, ubuntu 23.04